# C# confirm table row has been deleted from database

Tags: c#, sql

I've written a method which will try and delete a row from a db table based on a primary key id.  The problem i have is that the try block is always returning "Success" even if a record has already been deleted / or it doesn't exist.

```
public string delete_visit(int id)
        {
            string deleteResponse = null;
            string cnn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connname].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                string SQL = string.Empty;
                SQL = "DELETE FROM [" + dbname + "].[dbo].[" + tbname + "]  WHERE VisitorNumber = @IDNumber ";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@IDNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
                    command.Parameters["@IDNumber"].Value = id;
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        deleteResponse = "Success";

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        deleteResponse = "There was a problem deleting the visit from the database. Error message: " + ex.Message;
                    }
                }

            }

            return deleteResponse;
        }
```

I want to be able to tell if the row was affected.  I can do this in SQL Server Management Studio like so:

```
DELETE FROM Visits
WHERE VisitorNumber=88;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
PRINT 'Warning: No rows were updated';
```

So i want to know how do i plug in the @@ROWCOUNT bit into my c# so that i can tell if the row was deleted?

thanks

Comment: `DELETE FROM Visits
WHERE VisitorNumber=88; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` and check in your C# code returned value

Comment: Consider using stored procedures - writing SQL queries this way makes it difficult to separate the wheat from the chaff. You'd also need to rebuild and redeploy the solution if the SQL code changed. Yes, this isn't a big deal if you're just knocking something together but a huge deal if this is an enterprise solution being pushed out to hundreds of servers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx), indicating how many rows were affected.

So:

```
int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (rowsAffected == 0)
{
    deleteResponse = "No rows affected";
}
```

The problem is that this number can be influenced based on what the query actually does. Executing triggers or calling stored procedures could mess with the output, changing the affected number of rows. If you really must, then first execute a query where you check that the record with the given ID exists.

Comment: thanks @CodeCaster, this is perfect, it's a small scale app so this does the trick.